# iOS: When to release member objects?

Tags: ios, memory-management

When do i have to release objects declared in the .h file and allocated in my .m file viewdidload? Autorelease gives me an error. Do i have to release them in the

```
-(void)dealloc{

}
```

method (like properties)?

Thx

Comment: I thing you are not allocate  memory for that Obj.

Comment: if you are using  alloc, mutableCopy,new,copy for allocate memory . then  you release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first, add [super dealloc], it's important:

```
-(void)dealloc{
   [var1 release], var1 = nil;
   [var2 release], var2 = nil;
   [super dealloc];
}
```

Second, yes, instance variables that you have retained must be released by you manually.

Comment: is [super dealloc]| always the last statement in the dealloc method? Saw it often as the first one..

Comment: never, never, never put it in the middle or in the beginning of your dealloc method. Your subclass vars might be heavily dependent on the superclass vars, so the subclass must be released first for the safety matters. With the simple subclassing [super dealloc] in the beginning will work, but i'm recommending you to get used to write it at the end of the method - makes your code easy extendable and looking more professional. Also note, if you omit [super dealloc] the app doesn't crash but produce memory-leaks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [ARC](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) (the default in the latest version of Xcode), then retains/releases are automatically inserted and you only have to worry about the object graph (keeping references when you need to use an object, and avoiding circular references).

If not, you're correct that `dealloc` is the right place to release member variables. Although specifically for those created in `viewDidLoad`, remember that your view may be loaded/unloaded multiple times for the life of your controller, so consider using `viewDidUnload` to release those objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ARC (automatic reference counting), you don't.  That's done for you automatically.  If you're not using ARC then you do it manually in the dealloc like normal.  Note that new projects will use ARC automatically and ARC will give you an error if you try to `release`, `retain`, or `autorelease` and object.

Comment: no, i don´t use arc because of external libraries that do not support this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would in general release them in `dealloc`. But also if they're created in `viewDidLoad` then you might want to release them (and set the ivar to `nil`) in `viewDidUnload`, especially if the object can be recreated in its current state the next time `viewDidLoad` is called.

Of course if you're using ARC then you don't need to explicitly release your ivars in `dealloc` as ARC will generate a `dealloc` implementation which does this for you.

Comment: do i always have to release AND nil the objects?

Comment: In `viewDidUnload`, definitely yes. In `dealloc`, it depends. It doesn't hurt to `nil` them but you can read up on more questions here about that :-).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid serious problems regarding memory management and memory leaks u need to clarify ur doubts regarding objects allocation and releasing them. Try this link http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/memory-management.html